# Update Object Item in Vuex Array

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to manage a simple shopping cart of products. The products are stored on the state as an array called `items`

```
export const state = () => ({
  cart: {
    items: [],
  }
})
```

If a product is already been added to the cart, and someone tries to add it again, I'm trying to update the `quantity` field

```
addItem(state, product) {
  let cartProduct = state.cart.items.find((item, index) => {
    return item.id === product.id
  })
  cartProduct.quantity++;
});
```

This isn't working for me as it's not updating the state. Does anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's reactivity issue. You can make deep copy of cart to make store reactive:

```
   addItem(state, product) {
      let cartProduct = state.cart.items.find((item, index) => {
        return item.id === product.id
      })
      cartProduct.quantity++;
      state.cart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.cart))
    });
```

Another option is using `Vue.set`

Comment: Is there any benefit in using `.find(..)` to change the value of the object instead of using `state.cart.map(..)` (with `if(item.id == product.id) ...`) to change the cart directly?

Comment: `state.cart.map` might be better. Then you don't need to do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`